# How much bandwitdh is enough to work using Adobe Creative Cloud smoothly?

Tags: adobe-creative-cloud

My team need to work on a new project with customer, they want to directly work on Adobe Cloud, in Vietnam, internet line to a international server is expensive, so how much bandwitdh is enough for 10 clients to work smoothly on Adobe Cloud?

---

EDIT:

Which internet line bandwidth is fit for my 10 members team directly edit on Adobe Cloud: 10Mbps or 20Mbps? Or how could I measure it?

It very hard to increase bandwitch after contract signed.

Comment: This really is one of those "How long is a piece of string?" questions. You need to find out how much data you need to move & whether you can buy a line fast enough to move that in good time. With the internet, no server is any further away than any other [except by some milliseconds] & cost doesn't change by distance. Vietnam's average speeds are about 40mpbs these days - not great but not hopeless either - https://www.speedtest.net/global-index/vietnam

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for reply, my new project is design digital catalogue, and because internet fee is somekind expensive in my country, so 10Mbps bandwitdh line vs 20Mbps bandwitdh is very different, the question is which one is fit for my project? 10Mbps or 20Mbps?

Comment: We don't know, because we don't have any idea what your project requires.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry for dummy question, which information we need to estimate it?

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible to reasonably use cloud storage with these speeds. I suggest you give up on it and use a local network file storage.

Comment: @DanielB thanks for reply, which bandwidth speed is normally use for cloud storage?

Comment: No idea. Depends very much on the workflow. If you save often and have medium-size files maybe 50 Mbps upstream?